# Java text-based RPG - movement pattern for monsters

Tags: java

So I have an RPG with monsters and rooms and I want to give monsters movement patterns so every x turns they move to a specified room and cycle back.

So something like library -> lab -> home -> lab -> library.

My first thought was that the monster class should have a static ArrayList to keep track of the monsters, and then every monster has an ArrayList for the rooms it cycles through. Then on each turn if turn % x == 0 I move each monster into the next room on its ArrayList of rooms.

But I'm not sure what's the best way to keep track of where each monster is in its cycle, I could also add an iterator on the ArrayList of rooms for each monster that increments every 4 turns until it reaches the end and resets and use that to get the next room to move to but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Why not just keep track of the current index within the list of rooms? Alternatively rather than have the monster keep track of where it is have the rooms keep track of what monsters are inside it

Comment: I'd rather have something like a `Set<Room>` containing all possibles rooms available for the monsters to walk in. Each monster would have the `currentRoom` they are in so that they cannot walk to the same room again and then, picking a random room (or maybe with another strategy like your cycling) present in the `Set<Room>`.